# Old Sidekiq jobs retry forever. No visibility on Sidekiq UI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, backgroundworker, sidekiq

I have made a decent amount of changes to the process of one of my jobs over the last year.  Things like triggering it from `after_commit` instead of `after_create` on the respective Model as well as cleaning up the logic and covering corner cases

I see my old jobs from months ago retrying over and over again in my `Papertrail` logs on my Heroku Ruby on Rails app. The new ones are fine and I believe my changes have fixed any issues.  The problem is how do I stop all those old jobs and why do I not see them on my `Sidekiq` UI? The Sidekiq UI just shows a number of completed jobs, but 0 failed, dead, busy, or enqueued.  It says 0 yet I see the logs churning away.

I log the job ID's but have seen that [you cannot kill a specific job](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1459).  I have restarted my server multiple times with no luck.  Every day they try again.

I should note that all recent jobs are fine.  Anything within the last month or so do not repeat.  Out of the 5000 objects that had an `after_create` triggered job, only 1-60 are retrying.  The others passed and are fine

Answer (score 2):

If you know the `jid`'s you can do this from a rails console:

```
queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new("my_queue")
queue.each do |job|
  job.delete if job.jid == 'abcdef1234567890'
end
```

If it's in the retryset you can do:

```
query = Sidekiq::RetrySet.new
query.each do |job|
  job.delete if job.jid == 'abcdef1234567890'
end
```

If you can't delete because the jobs are inflight, stop your worker processes (ie shut 'em down) for a few minutes and then run the above.

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward but both those options yield 0 results in the loop.  I was just printing the jids instead of deleting.  I know its the same sidekiq instance because all the 'new' jobs show up in the logs and the sidekiq queue, but these 'old' ones only show up in the logs - not the sidekiq queue

Comment: I can't remember if the jid changes on retry.  Is there another qualifying job factor you can do for lookup?  maybe something in `job.args` that you can tell is from an older job?

Comment: I may have misspoken - there are no items in any queues.  It never hits the delete line (or the puts line in my case). The only thing i can think is that at some point the name of the queue changed, but i looked at my redis instance and dont see any other queue names besides mine ("certificates")

Comment: shut down your workers and check redis again, what you're saying doesn't make sense.

Comment: I restarted all the dynos (workers included) and it didn't seem to do anything.  Makes no sense to me either that's why I'm posting this. Cannot figure out where the jobs are hidden.  Not in any Sidekiq queue and not in Redis